# max-width of overflow:scroll element to match flex-grow parent elements width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container `#container` with a fixed width which has three children `.item`. Each have a flex-basis of 100px but the middle one `.item-grow` should grow so that all width of `#container` is used. This works like expected.

The `.item-grow` element has another children `#too-big` which could be wider than the available parent's width so its wrapped inside a `#scroll` container with `overflow: scroll` and `max-width: 100%`.

The problem is, that `#scroll` ignores `max-width: 100%` and forces the parent `.item-grow` to grow which foces the container `#container` to grow.

If I set `max-width: 296px` instead of `max-width: 100%` it works but I am looking for a dynamic (and CSS only) solution.

In the embedded code you can find a slider which changes the size of `#too-big`, you can clearly see that its growing the parents and not using the scrollbars.

```js
function setSize (newValue) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("too-big");
  elem.setAttribute("style",`width:${newValue}px; height:${newValue}px`);
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.item-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
.center-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 100%; /* I want this respect the current parents width */
  /* max-width: 296px; */
  max-height: 100%; /* I want this respect the current parents height */
  /* max-height: 200px; */
}
#too-big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min=100 max=500 value=100 oninput="setSize(this.value)" onchange="setSize(this.value)">
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item-grow">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
      <div class="scroll">
        <div id="too-big"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The green box is never bigger than its containers. The containers have `max-width: 100%`, `max-height: 100%` and `flex-grow: 1`.  So there's no reason for the scroll bars to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that work you can drop the `center-wrapper` and set `margin: auto` on the `scroll`.

Then the `item` need `min-width: 0` to allow it to be smaller than its content.

And for the `max-height: 100%` to work (cross browser), the `item-grow` need a height.

[Fiddle demo (with `overflow: auto` instead)](https://jsfiddle.net/zvxh6tr7/6/)

Stack snippet

```js
function setSize (newValue) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("too-big");
  elem.setAttribute("style",`width:${newValue}px; height:${newValue}px`);
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;            /*  added  */
  min-width: 0;                      /*  added  */
}
.item-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;                      /*  added  */
}
.scroll {
  margin: auto;                      /*  added  */
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
#too-big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min=100 max=500 value=100 oninput="setSize(this.value)" onchange="setSize(this.value)">
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item-grow">
      <div class="scroll">
        <div id="too-big"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```